# gdb - address of the last register value change?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, gdb, arm

While debugging an application, there is a point at which I wish to know the meaning of the value in r2 register. Is it possible, using gdb, to see at which instruction was the value of register r2 last changed before my breakpoint was struck? If that is impossible, is there a way to see from which address did the pc jump to the current one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible, using gdb, to see at which instruction was the value of register r2 last changed before my breakpoint was struck?

No.

> If that is impossible, is there a way to see from which address did the pc jump to the current one?

There are some processors that allow this, but (I believe) ARM is not one of them, so no, that's not possible either.